# Dirty clothes at the reception

Tags: prison-architect

I have a laundry where 4 prisoners work (4 washers, 3 carts, 2 boards), 5 janitors and yet, my reception is filled with dirty clothes that no one bothers to pick up.

The normal laundry cycle seems to work good, because no one is complaining about clothes. But still, the dirty ones lie around **only** in the reception.

What am I missing?

Comment: From the Logistics menu, you can assign a Laundry room to specific parts of your prison. Have you checked if this was set correctly? I'm writing this from memory, I don't have access to the game at the moment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I havent assigned anything yet through logistics (prison is not that large that it would be needed) but I'll check when I'm home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to wikia:

> After the prisoners get all the dirty clothes, they will group on a
>   random place on your laundry, not getting any work done and slowly
>   raising complaints.
>
> Prisoners won't move the laundry basket to collect and replace dirty
>   clothes. This bug is sometimes caused by a bugged laundry cart,
>   dismantling all carts servicing that area and then reassembling is a
>   possible solution.

Another more proabable solution I found was to close off open areas between buildings. Especially the reception area.

A less likely solution would be to create a path of concrete tiles from the laundry to the reception. Though, I doubt that would be it.

Comment: I will check those things out and report back.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka Great! I hope it helps!